# OCaml Marshal very large data structure

Tags: stream, ocaml, marshalling

I would like to send a very large (~8GB) datastructure through the network, so I use the Marshal module to transform it into Bytes.

My problem is that the memory doubles, because we need to store both representations (initial data and Marshaled data).

Is there a simple way to Marshal into a Stream instead ? This would avoid to have the full Marshalled representation of the initial datastructure.

I thought of Marshaling to an out_channel in which I opened a pipe with a second thread and reading from the pipe in the main thread into s Stream, but I guess there might be a simpler solution.

Thanks !

---

Edit: Answer to a comment:

In the toplevel :

```
let a = Array.make (1024*1024*1024) 0. ;; (* Takes 8GB of RAM *)
let data = Marshal.to_bytes a [Marshal.Closures] ;; (* Takes an extra 8GB *)
```

Comment: Could you show us your code? How do you communicate with the network?

Comment: what do you mean by the _stream_?

Comment: @ivg : the Stream module of the standard library : https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Stream.html

Comment: @PatJ : When you create a 8GB array in the toplevel, you can see that it takes 8GB of resident memory. Still in the toplevel, if you marshall it you can see that you use 16BG of resident memory.

Comment: It really might help to know how you're writing to the network, as @PatJ is asking. Perhaps you can stream directly into the network as a channel.

Comment: I want to broadcast data with MPI, so unfortunately it is not possible to use a channel. https://github.com/xavierleroy/ocamlmpi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible. You would have to modify the Marshal module to stream the data as it marshals something and to reconstruct the data in place without buffering it all first.

In the short run it might be simpler to implement your own specialized marshal function specific to your data. For an 8GiB array you might want to switch to using BigArray so you can send/recv the data without having to copy it.

Note: A 8GiB array will use 16GiB if the GC ever copies it, at least temporary.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, MPI only allows to send data packets with a known size, not a stream of data. You could implement a custom stream type that split an incoming flow of data to packets of constant, small size (on close, you flush whatever remains in the buffer).

Also, you only can marshall arbitrary long data to a channel, because otherwise you take up too many space.

And then, you need to have a way to connect the channel to the stream, which AFAIK is not easily possible. Maybe you could start antoer ocaml process: the process would convert the flow of bytes (you can wrap a custom stream over `Stream.of_channel`) and send it through MPI. The main process would marshall data to the process's input channel.

Comment: Your answer is similar to my complicated workaround with threads (MPI may cause problems when you fork). So I guess your answer is "no, there is no simple solution". Thanks!

Comment: I am afraid that's the case, but I'd love to be proven wrong. Good luck.